# LogCat - Não aparece

Tags: android

Estou fazendo o Exemplo5 do cap 3 do livro Google Android 3ºed(Ricardo R.Lecheta), onde aplicando um filtro para exibir no logcat. só que não está me retornando nada.

```
package br.livro.android.cap3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;


public class Exemplo5 extends Activity {
    private static final String CATEGORIA = "livro";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Verbose
        Log.v(CATEGORIA, "log de verbose");

        // Debug
        Log.d(CATEGORIA, "log de debug");

        // Info
        Log.i(CATEGORIA, "log de info");

        // Warn
        Log.w(CATEGORIA, "log de alerta");

        // Error
        Log.e(CATEGORIA, "log de erro", new RuntimeException("teste de erro"));
    }
}
```

[image: print]

Comment: Eu estou sem o Eclipse aqui (usando o [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html)), mas você já tentou rodar o logcat na mão? (`adb logcat`). Talvez o IDE esteja redirecionando a `stdout` ou algo assim ([Documentação Oficial da Google](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html)).

Comment: Faça como disse o @AnthonyAccioly a ver se resulta.

Comment: utilizando o comando (`adb logcat`) me retorna algumas informações mais nada do que eu digitei na minha classe, tem que utilizar filtro ou deveria aparecer?

Comment: @Josinaldo quando você tira o filtro e fica usando o emulador, os logs ficam aparecendo?

Comment: Testei em outro projeto e funcionou :), deve ser algum erro que fiz na aplicação, obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Tente abrir a perspectiva do DDMS (em cima a direita), e selecionar o device que você deseja visualizar o LogCat Output.

Exemplo: selecionando o device "015DC1F50600" para exibir o LogCat.

[image: DDMS]

Comment: nada :(, pior que nem posso pular está parte do livro porque é essencial.

(http://s16.postimg.org/eynkqshnp/Screenshot_erro_eclipse2.png)